# SCALA - import a trait in a worksheet

Tags: scala, import, worksheet, traits

Everything is in the title : How do I do for import a trait in a worksheet for testing it? I have a function in that trait that I want to test..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just import it like you always would:

```
import com.mytrait.MyTrait
```

Comment: The trait would be to be instantiated tho ?